.Net 8 XUnit: Should my tests use real data or how to mock MySql with CQRS?
I'm creating tests for our .Net 8 API. We use MySql for data storage and CQRS pattern for queries.
In my personal opinion, I shouldn't use the real database for testing, because you will use an existing set of data (from which to do the assertions) which might have changed at any moment, and so the tests would fail in the future, but at the same time I cannot (shouldn't) insert fake data (which would be permanent) into the real database.
My problem is I don't know how to mock MySql database within our CQRS architecture, or how to use in-memory generated data, so I'm stuck.
In our query handlers we inject an interface with a "QueryAsync" method which implementation creates a connection to MySql for the queries using just MySqlConnection, but don't know how to test that.
I could just mock "QueryAsync" method (the result of it) with a sample set of data, and it works, but not sure if this is the correct way to go, I mean, I'll be generating a sample set of data as a result for the method, and then I'll be comparing this set with itself, so the tests won't ever fail (I guess).
In resume, which would be the way to go to test a controller get method in a cqrs architecture that uses mysql as database?
I'll paste some relevant pieces of code in case it helps.
Program.cs:
await RunServer.RunAsync<Startup>(
    args,
    (builder, options) =>
    {
        ...
        options.OtherServices = () =>
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloudStackDbUnitOfWork, CloudStackDbUnitOfWork>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory, MySqlCloudStackCoreConnectionFactory>();
            ...
        };
        ...
    },
);

ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory:
public interface ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory
{
    DbConnection CreateConnection(Region region);

    Task<(int Count, TOut[] Data)> QuerySearchAsync<TDbItem, TOut>(IRegionRepository regionRepository, string fetchDataQuery, string? countDataQuery = null, Dictionary<string, string>? columnModelModel = null, Paging? paging = null, ColumnName[]? order = null, string[]? excludedOrder = null, Func<Region, TDbItem, TOut>? transform = null, object? queryParam = null, Func<Region, bool>? filter = null, bool skipDbPaging = false, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken)) where TOut : class;

    Task<int> ExecuteAsync(IRegionRepository regionRepository, string sql, object? @params = null, Func<Region, bool>? filter = null, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken));
}

MySqlCloudStackCoreConnectionFactory (just the skeleton):
public sealed class MySqlCloudStackCoreConnectionFactory : ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory
{
    public MySqlCloudStackCoreConnectionFactory()
    {
        
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection(Region region)
    {
        return new MySqlConnection(GetConnString(region));
    }

    public async Task<(int Count, TOut[] Data)> QuerySearchAsync<TDbItem, TOut>(IRegionRepository regionRepository, string fetchDataQuery, string? countDataQuery = null, Dictionary<string, string>? columnModelModel = null, Paging? paging = null, ColumnName[]? order = null, string[]? excludedOrder = null, Func<Region, TDbItem, TOut>? transform = null, object? param = null, Func<Region, bool>? filter = null, bool skipDbPaging = false, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken)) where TOut : class
    {
        ...
        DbConnection connection = CreateConnection(region);
        ...
    }

    public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync(IRegionRepository regionRepository, string sql, object? @params = null, Func<Region, bool>? filter = null, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ...
        DbConnection connection = CreateConnection(region);
        ...
    }
}

QueryHandler (CQRS):
public sealed class SearchQuery : VdcQuery<SearchResponse>
{
    public SearchQuery(IdentityInfo identity, string? correlationId) :
        base(identity, correlationId)
    {
        
    }
}
internal sealed class SearchQueryHandler : IQueryHandlerValidator<SearchQuery>, IVdcQueryHandler<SearchQuery, SearchResponse>
{
    private readonly IRegionRepository _regionRepository;
    private readonly ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory _cloudStackCoreConnectionFactory;

    public SearchQueryHandler(
        ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory cloudStackCoreConnectionFactory,
        IRegionRepository regionRepository)
    {
        _cloudStackCoreConnectionFactory = cloudStackCoreConnectionFactory;
        _regionRepository = regionRepository;
    }

    public async ValueTask<SearchResponse> HandleAsync(SearchQuery request, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        var sql = GetSearchQuerySql();

        var regionFilter = GetFilters(request.Filter, sql);

        var (count, data) = await _cloudStackCoreConnectionFactory.QuerySearchAsync<SearchResponse.Account, SearchResponse.Account>(
            _regionRepository,
            sql.fetch.ToString(),
            sql.count.ToString(),
            paging: request.Paging,
            order: request.Order,
            filter: regionFilter.filters,
            transform: (regionId, item) =>
            {
                item.RegionId = regionId;
                return item;
            },
            queryParam: regionFilter.param,
            ct: ct
        );

        return new SearchResponse(count, data);
    }

    public ValueTask<IResponse> ValidatorAsync(SearchQuery request, RequestValidator<SearchQuery> validator, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        ...
    }

    private (StringBuilder fetch, StringBuilder count) GetSearchQuerySql()
    {
        var fetch = new StringBuilder($"""
            SELECT 
                UUID AS {nameof(SearchResponse.Account.Id)}, 
                account_name AS {nameof(SearchResponse.Account.Name)} 
            FROM cloud.account acc 
            WHERE acc.state != 'disabled' AND removed IS NULL
        """);

        return (fetch, ...);
    }
}

Unit Testing:
In this next lab pay attention on how I do mock the results of QuerySearchAsync through the implementation MySqlMock and IAccountList, because this is the part I'm not sure it's correct according what it is expected from a database test, I mean:
I think I'm mocking a method result, and not the database as it should be.
I will always get the expected results, because in fact I'm creating the expected results.
Lab we use to initialize tests:
public sealed class Lab
{    
    public async Task<EventSend?> InitAsync(IServiceProvider provider, bool useEvents = false)
    {
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a lab with the requirement of this project
    /// </summary>
    public static Lab Create(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        var appFactory = Vdc.Libs.AspNet.Testing.Setup.Factory<Startup, InnerDbContextRead, InnerDbContextWrite>(
            out var client,
            out var authorize,
            out var identity,
            out var faker,
            role: $"{VdcSecurity.Role.Management},{VdcSecurity.Role.ManagementAdmin}",
            output: output,
            setup: services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IAccountList, AccountList>();
                services.AddScoped<ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory, MySqlMock>();
            }
        );
        return new Lab(identity, appFactory, client, authorize, faker);
    }

    public class AccountList : IAccountList
    {
        SearchResponse.Account[] IAccountList.accounts => [
            CreateAccount("Account1", AccountTypes.Managed),
            CreateAccount("Account2", AccountTypes.Managed),
            CreateAccount("Account3", AccountTypes.Unmanaged),
            CreateAccount("Account4", AccountTypes.Internal),
            CreateAccount("Account5", AccountTypes.Hybrid),
        ];

        private SearchResponse.Account CreateAccount(string accountName, AccountTypes typeId)
        {
            SearchResponse.Account account;
            account = new SearchResponse.Account
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = accountName,
                AccountOrder = 0,
                RegionId = 1
            };
            return account;
        }
    }   
}

MySqlMock:
public interface IAccountList
{
    SearchResponse.Account[] accounts { get; }
}

public class MySqlMock : ICloudStackCoreConnectionFactory
{
    IAccountList _accounts;
    public MySqlMock(IAccountList accounts)
    {
        _accounts = accounts;
    }

    public DbConnection CreateConnection(Vdc.Libs.Region region)
    {
        return new MySqlConnection();
    }

    public async Task<(int Count, TOut[] Data)> QuerySearchAsync<TDbItem, TOut>(
        IRegionRepository regionRepository, 
        string fetchDataQuery, 
        string? countDataQuery = null, 
        Dictionary<string, string>? columnModelModel = null, 
        Paging? paging = null, 
        ColumnName[]? order = null, 
        string[]? excludedOrder = null, 
        Func<Vdc.Libs.Region, TDbItem, TOut>? transform = null, 
        object? param = null, 
        Func<Vdc.Libs.Region, bool>? filter = null, 
        bool skipDbPaging = false, 
        CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken)) where TOut : class
    {
        return (_accounts.accounts.Length, _accounts.accounts as TOut[]);
    }

    public Task<int> ExecuteAsync(IRegionRepository regionRepository, string sql, object? @params = null, Func<Vdc.Libs.Region, bool>? filter = null, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

My Test:
[Theory]
[InlineData(0, 5)]
public async Task GetFirst5Element_OrderByName_ReturnOnly5ElementOrderByName(int page, int expectedElements)
{
    using var scope = _lab.AppFactory.Services.CreateScope();
    var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;

    // Arrange
    var events = await _lab.InitAsync(provider, false);

    // Act 
    var request = new SearchRequest(
        null,
        new Paging { Page = page, PageSize = expectedElements },
        [new Vdc.Libs.Web.ColumnNameRequest(nameof(SearchResponse.Account.Name)) { Asc = true }]
    );
    var response = await _client.SearchAsync(_lab.Identity, request);

    // Assert

    //TODO: still need to check the results with the sample data I've created
    response.Results.GetType().Should().Be(typeof(List<SearchResponse.Account>));
    response.Results.Count().Should().Be(expectedElements);
}

IApiService:
public interface IAccountsApiService : IApiService
{
    Task<SearchResponse> SearchAsync(IdentityInfo identity, SearchRequest request, string? correlationId = null, CancellationToken ct = default);
}

public sealed class AccountsApiService : BaseApiService, IAccountsApiService
{
    private readonly AuthorizeOptions _options;

    public AccountsApiService(IOptions<AuthorizeOptions> options, IApiClient apiClient, ILogger<AccountsApiService> logger) 
        : base(apiClient, logger: logger)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public async Task<SearchResponse> SearchAsync(IdentityInfo identity, SearchRequest request, string? correlationId = null, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        var (response, _) = await ApiClient.SendAsync<SearchResponse>(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            "/api/accounts",
            message => message.AddAuthorization(identity, _options.ApiKey, correlationId),
            model: request,
            ct: ct
        );
        return response!;
    }
}

Controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize(Roles = ...]
public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public AccountsController(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SearchResponse>> Get(
        [FromServices][IsSensitive] IQueryDispatcher dispatcher,
        [FromQuery] SearchRequest request,
        [IsSensitive] CancellationToken ct = default
    )
    {
        var identity = HttpContext.GetIdentity();
        var query = new SearchQuery(identity, HttpContext.TraceIdentifier)
        {
            Filter = request.Filter,
            Order = request.Order?.ToColumnName() ?? Constants.Page.Sorting,
            Paging = request.Paging ?? Constants.Page.Paging,
        };
        var result = await dispatcher.DispatchAsync(_provider, query, ct);

        return result.ToActionResult(this);
    }
}

Do you think my approach for unit testing this query handler is correct?
If not, how should I do it?
Edit 1: About what I expect to test.
In other APIs we created, what we test is that the response is the expected one, I mean, given a sample (fake) set of data (created by us in the "Lab" class) we test that the query handler (in the end, the "QuerySearchAsync") method returns what is expected to return.
In the case of this API (compared to our other APIs where tests are already working great with SQL Server), this API uses MySql, and I don't know how to mock MySql to accomplish that.
I'd need a MySql mocked set of data (that I would create in the "Lab" class) that can be used with the query handler.
Maybe you could add in your answers something about that, or at least a link that would be advisable for me to check.

please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78724919/net-xunit-should-my-tests-use-real-data-or-how-to-mock-mysql-with-cqrs "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Hello @gnat, didn't know. It's the first time I heard about this word, cross-post. Is stack-overflow and stack-exchange the same site? What should I do? Delete one of the posts?

@DiegoPerez: yes, deleting would be find

Hi @Doc Brown, already deleted from stackoverflow.

@DiegoPerez: first of all, I think you should try to shorten the code sections. But I guess the question itself is ok here. Could be ok on Stackoverflow as well.

Thanks for the clarification @Doc Brown. Shortened them a bit. Let's see if it looks better now.

Duplicate of How to test the data access layer?

SQL is a programming language. You probably do want to test the queries. Sometimes manual testing is OK, but I've had great success with automated integration tests that spin up a database container and then run the tests in a throwaway database/namespace. This is slow (one of my containers needs 30s to spin up and 1s per setup/teardown), but this has caught so many problems that wouldn't have been found by mocking. It also makes it easy and natural to write tests. The https://testcontainers.com/ project could be a good place to get started.

Thank you very much for your input @amon. I'll check the link you provide.

The answer here is as often "depends what you're trying to test".

If you're trying to unit test an edge case (e.g. that the application does not crash if the query errors), you almost certainly want to mock the query response because this kind of situation is very hard to reliably reproduce without a mock.
If you're trying to unit test a bit of your business logic (e.g. that your business logic returns "go" if the widget record in the database is green), you probably want to mock the database response itself.
If you're trying to integration test something (e.g. that the right response is given over your REST API for a specific query), you may be best standing up a database with known data in it, maybe with Docker, maybe by replacing your MySQL adapter with SQLite or similar.
If you're trying to end-to-end test something (e.g. that the performance of your whole app is within acceptable limits), you probably want a copy or read replica of the live production database.

That all said, a function as generic as
Task<(int Count, TOut[] Data)> QuerySearchAsync<TDbItem, TOut>(
  IRegionRepository regionRepository,
  string fetchDataQuery,
  <approximately 27 billion other parameters>
) where TOut : class;

is probably part of your issue here. It feels like you've got a business-logic aware layer missing in your application.

Hello @Philip Kendall, I edited the question and rewritten all the initial part in a much more clear way, and what is more, I commented in a clearer way what's the purpose of my tests, that are integration tests. Could you please have a look at my edits to see if that helps to add more info in your question? Thanks, I appreciate your time.

Please don't edit questions in such a way as to invalidate existing answers - that undoes the work that people have put into your original question. If you've now realised you asked the wrong question, you can always ask a new question.

Thanks for pointing this out @Philip Kendal, because I didn't realize, but you are right. I reverted the question to its original state and I will create a new one.

Given that we have easy spin up of databases in containers these days I think the best solution for testing is to spin up a real database and throw it away afterwards.
You can go further and use WebApplicationFactory to spin up your API and run tests against that rather than unit testing your controllers.
If you use both in conjunction your will get nice easy end to end integration tests with full code coverage.
If you look at your code, really it's not doing anything other than move data out of a database into an object and then serialising and sending that object over the network.
It's that functionality that you want to test and you need a database and a network to test it.

Is my SQL correct
Am I converting the dataset to objects correctly
Is my controller action bound to the correct address
Does the serialisation of the object work

These are all questions best answered by an integration test.
Save you unit tests for pure functions and business logic.
